# RaspberryPi 3 no network after first restart

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I just downloaded the raspbian buster with desktop image (2019-09-26). I connected it to my home ethernet and boot it up as usual. The first boot was fine and the internet connection was working properly.

I answered the initial set up wizard questions and reboot. After reboot the network is dead. Neither the ethernet nor the wifi connection works.

I tried with and without installing updates at initial start up. I doesn’t matter once I reboot, the network doesn’t work any more. I even tried and older buster image with the same result.

I switched to the latest stretch image now. It is working fine.

Any idea why buster doesn’t work after reboot?

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Someone say it's an hw issue. I solved with an ethernet reset on /etc/rc.local

so:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

write this line

```
(sleep 30s; ethtool -r eth0;) &
```